# How to change remembered windows client password in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, network-shares, samba

I was opening another computer (with windows 8) in my LAN, from Windows Vista client. It asked my password and I have entered wrong one, and also checked to remember it. Now I can't access windows8 computer anymore (says something like "can't get access to computer"). Probably it remembered wrong password.

How to force it to reask the password?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following procedure, you should be able to edit or delete the password: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/manage-stored-passwords

Here is what it says:

1. Open User Accounts by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **User Accounts and Family Safety** (or clicking **User Accounts**, if you are connected to a network domain), and then clicking **User Accounts**.
2. In the left pane, click **Manage your network passwords**.
3. Select the password you want to manage.
4. Click **Edit**, make the change you want, and then click **OK**.